# OpenGL in xcode 4

Tags: opengl, xcode

I'm just getting started with OpenGL with lot's of ideas on my head that i want to experiment, i started reading the OpenGL Superbible book which looks amazing but i am having a super hard time making any of the examples work on xcode 4.

Can anyone tell me how to set up a project to run any of this OpenGL Examples?

Thanks!

BTW: I am reading the 4th edition and not the 5th one since someone recommended me doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are trying to learn OpenGL 2.1. The good thing about this release is that it easy to get started with and get something up on the screen. The bad thing about OpenGL 2.1 is that things has changed quite a bit in OpenGL 3.x and 4.x, so when you want to take your graphics programming a step further, you need to learn a few more things.

Anyway there is a lot of tutorials about how to setup XCode with OpenGL 2.1. A good one is:

- http://mockid.net/?p=5

Comment: thanks! So you think it's a bad idea to learn 2.1 then?

Comment: I still think 2.1 is quite important. Most examples and tutorials on the internet are a few years old and uses 2.1. In the end it is up to you to decide. OpenGL 3.x has a very steep learning curve and you will be quite challenged in the beginning, whereas in OpenGL 2.1 the concepts are introduced more slowly - but you will here learn come legacy techniques no longer used in OpenGL 3.x.